# Can you help identify this vintage aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification, seaplane

[image]

Please help identify this aircraft. Photo taken in Rijeka, Croatia early 1900s

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a **[Dornier Do D](http://www.letletlet-warplanes.com/2008/05/13/dornier-do-d/)**, a floatplane torpedo bomber variant of the [Dornier Komet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Komet), which was built for the [Yugoslav Royal Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Yugoslav_Navy). It's considerably bigger than it looks in your picture!

**203** served with the Yugoslavian 20th Hydrosquadron from 1927, originally based in Kumbor, Montenegro. In this early variant, the pilot sat in the forward cockpit, right under the wing - you can just see him in the second picture - a bold design feature. Later variants rearranged the fuselage and cockpit. Here is the exact same plane -

[image: Dornier Do D] [source](http://www.letletlet-warplanes.com/2008/05/13/dornier-do-d/)
[image: Dornier Do D] [source](https://ru-aviation.livejournal.com/3287641.html)

[image: Dornier Do D]
[source](http://www.shipbucket.com/vehicles/8760)

Comment: Outstanding answer!

Comment: Wow.  Thank you for the information.  That is way more than I was expecting.  -Chris

Comment: @ChrisVolker *That is way more than I was expecting* - so show your delight by accepting the question  (checkmark under the votes at the left of the answer, turns green when checked)